# How to add a build time to a file archive as a post-build macro?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, post-build-event

I want to pack the project into a zip-file and have the build date time (or the current date time) as part of the zip-filename.

```
$(TargetDir)\7za.exe a release.zip *
```

So it would be nice to incorporate the date into the release.zip, something like release-14-3-2010-22_56.zip

Is it possible to define custom post-build macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call batch files as post build events.

```
call "$(SolutionDir)zip.bat"
```

and have the batch file read the date time.

[Here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/956/windows-batch-file-bat-to-get-current-date-in-mmddyyyy-format/) is an example